# Alignment of Search Button on Ask Help Page

Tags: feature-request

When going to ask a question, I noticed this on the "How to Ask" page and it kind of triggered my OCD.

[image: misaligned button]

The search button is definitely shorter than the textbox. In my opinion, it looks a little weird -- I think it would look better if it was the same height as the textbox, or maybe vertically aligned in the center of the textbox.

EDIT: Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?) to the referenced page

Comment: what is the link of this page?

Comment: @TemaniAfif "I noticed this on the 'How to Ask' page and it kind of..."

Comment: @SheshankS. and the link is? :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif never mind lol

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092724/align-inline-block-divs-to-top-of-container-element ... :p `vertical-align:top` will fix the issue

Comment: `.ask-advice-search-container > * { vertical-align: middle }` It looks a couple of pixels out if you use `top`.

Comment: To me as a UX expert (Not really) I don't see this as being that bad...There are many more things that need fixing than this.