# "Answer your own question" is vertically misaligned on "Ask" page

Tags: bug, asking-questions

On the "[ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)" page, the link-text against label "Answer your own question" is vertically misaligned:

[image]

<sub>The fix would probably require the CSS class "va-middle" on the hyphen and the "share your own knowledge" hyperlink.</sub>

Comment: vertical-alignment everything, related : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371462/alignment-of-search-button-on-ask-help-page

Comment: @TemaniAfif looks like a dev forgot their coffee :p

Comment: I don't accept rectangular boxes or straight lines, where are the freehand circles????